# How to force intellij idea to advice a override method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, overriding

I have following interface:

```
public interface Formula {
    double calculate(int a);

    default double sqrt(int a) {
        return Math.sqrt(a);
    }
}
```

And I have following main method:

[image]

I want that IDE advice me method to override.

Does this feature exist in intellij idea ?

### after getting answer:

If `Ctrl+O` doesn't work - check following picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Intellij to generate methods by using `ctrl+shift+space`. Type the variable name and after typing `new` press the combination mentioned above and hit `enter` it will generate all the methods [image] . 
If you are missing few methods then hit `F2` or click to navigate to the problem and then hit `alt+enter` [image]  [image] . 
Lastly if you are inside the class then use `ctrl+o` to see the list of available methods that you can override [image] [image] [image]

Comment: ok. But if I deleted one method and when want to insert this one

Comment: For example I have interface with 5 methods. 2 mandatory to overrride and 3 default methods. 2 mandatory methods already overriden and I want to override one of the three.

Comment: then I click ctrl+o I see only Object methods

Comment: @gstackoverflow I added some more screenshots

Comment: Please show situation when you have implement 1 method already and click ctrl+o to implement second

Comment: @gstackoverflow I added some more screenshots

Comment: thanks. I figured out the reason)))http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/141221/1c708cb30a.jpg

Comment: @gstackoverflow Glad it helps, you can always upvote if you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an autocomplete feature that takes the `@Override` annotation and completes from there, but you can always position the caret within the class and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, to get a pop-up suggesting all the method you can override.

Comment: at this picture I show what I see when I click ctrl + O

Comment: alternatively you can remove the @override and either use the intent on the error (Alt + Enter) or Press Crtl + Space to get a Proposal

Answer (score 0):

Create your Class and Press Alt+Insert to override Class Methods

```
  Formula formula = new Formula()
  {
     //Click here and Press Alt+Insert
  }
```

good luck

Comment: it's must worked,try convert interface to abstract class and extends it,do what i said again and tell me what was result

Comment: if you have Just 1 method in your Interface and Override that,you can't override more than 1!

Comment: But if I have more than 1 method?

Comment: then you have one or more methods in your interface that should be override by each class are implements that Interface!then you can press alt+insert to override the methods or press Ctrl + O to override them(very quickly)